# jinja2 rendering report variable not defined

Tags: scope, jinja2

I have a list which has dict as its element. The rendering got below failure. Can someone help here. Thanks very much.

```html
{% for i in mylist if 'name' in i %}
  {% set v = i['name'] %}
{% else %}
  {% set v = 'notfound' %}
{% endfor %}
{% set mydict = { 'name' : v } %}
```

It always report that v is not defined. Really confusing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should try to **define** `v` outside `for` and `else` blocs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply first. However, defining v outside doesn't work. Below is the updated code pieces, the v is assigned to 'pre-defined', which is not expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this is jinja2 scope. Here is the way to workaround it.

`{% set vlist = []  %}
    {% set mylist = [ {'name':'myvalue'} ] %}
    {% for i in mylist if 'name' in i %}
      {% do vlist.append(i['name']) %}
      {% break %}
    {% else %}
      {% do vlist.append('notfoundinlist') %}
    {% endfor %}`